# Homemade electromagnet safety

Tags: electromagnetic

How safe is it to use a homemade electromagnet from a microwave transformer such as the one in this link [Homemade Electromagnet from Microwave oven transformer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/213390/homemade-electromagnet-from-microwave-oven-transformer)
I am helping my 10 year old son with his science experiment but not sure if it's safe.

Comment: It would vary somewhere between really hurting your finger to smashing it off if you let one get between the magnet and ferrous metal. You can improve the safety by putting a piece of plastic of some thickness (like 1/2 inch or more) between the electromagnet and anything it can touch. That will reduce the pull you get as you get really close.

Comment: If for some reason you have one that plugs into a wall, that is obviously a shock hazard.

Comment: That should be inside a wooden or plastic case to call it safe!

Comment: also the coils have protective coating and should be wrapped with tape and protected from getting damage while your son is using this.  if any coils get damaged and shorted he will have a very bad day!

Comment: Thanks for the comments but aside from the obvious, I was more worried about the magnetic waves and any non visible radiation if there is any? We are just using a 12 V small bike battery

Comment: There won't be any weird and harmful rays from an electromagnet powered by a DC supply.

Answer (score 1):

What a wonderful time to be able to teach SAFETY,  not only to your 10 year old, but to all of his classmates.  Safety is always on topic here on EE SE.

Children are enamoured with magnetism, and displays of fireworks, and squished things.

Think this through VERY carefully.  Consider the implications of a magnetism demonstration that builds upon safety.

And of course with the admonition of "ONLY UPON ADULT SUPERVISION".

Use the other comments and answers to guide you.

Then demonstrate how a grape can be squished (like a human's finger).

No worry's about radiation

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the previous question, it is "not safe to plug into mains" (120 or 220 volts, AC). Someone with sufficient knowledge and experience could do this safely.

A voltage of 24 volts or lower is not likely to cause a dangerous electrical shock.

Even the current from a 1.5 volt battery can cause fire or burned skin if it is connected to something that will concentrate the heat into something small like the spring of a retractable ballpoint pen.

The current from a 12 volt car battery can cause a much more significant fire or burned skin hazard.

As pointed out in a comment, it is likely possible to make a magnet sufficiently powerful to cause a mechanical injury.